# Grub2 w/ RAID5 and btrfs "error: unknown filesystem"

Tags: mdadm, raid5, grub2, btrfs

I have a Virtual Machine (in ESXi 5.1) running Ubuntu Server 12.04. When I try to boot my system I grub2 tells me "error: unknown filesystem". I've tried booting a Live CD then reinstalling grub from both a chrooted environment and by supplying the --root-directory option. I've even tried a boot-repair CD (results [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5765582/)) and reinstalling grub. Whatever I use to fix it, I'm getting the error "Path `/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting."

To complicate things I'm running a RAID5 array (5 disks) using mdadm and btrfs for my filesystem. The btrfs tools that ship with Ubuntu 12.04 are really old. I've added ppa:cjwatson/grub (currently grub2 ver 2.00-2) and ppa:yofel/btrfs (currently btrfs-tools ver. 0.20~git20130524~650e656-0daily13) to my software sources to get more up to date utilities, with no help. The system was previously working before switching from a 4 disk RAID0 setup. I think this may have been the first reboot since the upgrade, but it was running fine for weeks using RAID5.

Comment: By adding a listing in device.map for the RAID array, I can get grub-install to run, but booting tells gives me an error of no such device.

Answer (score 1):

Grub can't actually boot from anything but a raid 1 or raid 0 mdadm device.
You will need to add a /boot device somewhere and just set that up in raid 1/0/raw.

I would do something like this

the 2 new volumes below {a,b} can be file backed but should be on separate physical disks.

```
/dev/sd{a,b}1 mdadm raid 1 /boot (2 new disks (500MB or so)) 
/dev/sd{c..g}1 mdadm  raid 5 / (current disks)
```

Comment: Not correct.  On a workstation, I'm successfully booting a RAID6 mdadm device.  There is also a report of booting RAID-5 on the Gentoo forums http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-888624-start-0.html

Comment: The kernel's boot time assembly of RAID arrays only works for RAID 0 or 1, but isn't that deprecated for initramfs?  I don't find any limit on grub2, but a lot of sources claim it works.

Comment: Oh that is very cool. i may have to look into that.

Comment: For now, I'm going with this, except using the raid1 support in btrfs (for data checks & easier maintenance).  As easy as 2 new virtual disks are to create, I may just wait for them to finish RAID5 support in btrfs before looking at a proper fix without extra disks.

Comment: replication with parity in btrfs is just going to be awesome when complete. my next FS upgrade will be to a btrfs based system as well. really good choice.